# JavaFX TabPane - Change one tab, update the others

Tags: java, tabs, javafx, updates

I have a TabPane with 10 tabs (each with its controller). In one of them I have a table 'categories' where the user can add / edit / delete categories.
The other tabs have the same table 'categories', smaller, in read-only mode, where the user can only select categories.
Then, when the table 'categories' is modified in the categories tab, what I want is for all other tables categories of the other tabs are updated.
What I thought is (not implemented yet), on the top panel to put a listener that detects tab changes and, when the user leaves the categories tab, check if changes have been made.
If so, call all the controllers involved to update their own tables of categories.

The question I have is, if there is a less cumbersome way to do this. Something like sending a message 'table has been changed' and all the 'listeners' tabs of the message update their tables. Similar to a locally JMS, not client-server. Is there something like this messaging service that can be employed within the same application or the solution that I raised above is the most consistent? I think the question is more Java than JavaFX.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to hold the categories in an ObservableList at some top level (say in your Application sub class) and have all the tables share a reference to that list (`table.setItems(yourList)`). Whenever a change is made in the categories tab, the other tabs will automatically reflect the change.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was thinking in a 'generic solution' you know.. to apply it anywhere. Well, in the meantime I will try your solution. Thanks!